# how can i redirect a single form to 2 pages with same data in php

Tags: php, sql

How can i redirect single form to 2 separate pages? Can anyone help me to get the same data to 2 separate pages?

i have tried to types of code

```
<?php

if (isset($_POST['Submit']) || isset($_POST['COD'])) {
    // handle textarea

    if (isset($_POST['Submit'])) {
        header("Location: Pay.php");
        exit();
    }

    header("Location: cod.php");
    exit();
}

?>
```

Here is my code:

```
<form name="form1" onsubmit="return validate()" method="POST" class="contact-form">
                         <input type="hidden" name="command" />
                         <div class="col-sm-12">
                                        <p align="center" class="contact-form-author">
                                        ORDER TOTAL : Rs. <?php echo get_order_total()?>

                                        </p>
                                    </div>

                                    <div class="col-sm-12">
                                        <p class="contact-form-author">
                                            <input type="hidden" value="<?php echo get_order_total()?>.00" name="price" placeholder="Name">
                                        </p>
                                    </div>

                                    <div class="col-sm-12">
                                        <p class="contact-form-author">
                                            <input type="text" required="required" name="name" placeholder="Name">
                                        </p>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="col-sm-12">
                                        <p class="contact-form-author">
                                            <input type="text" required="required" name="address" placeholder="Address">
                                        </p>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="col-sm-12">
                                        <p class="contact-form-email">
                                            <input type="email" required="required" name="email" placeholder="Email">
                                        </p>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="col-sm-12">
                                        <p class="contact-form-subject">
                                            <input type="text" required="required" name="phone"  placeholder="Phone">
                                        </p>
                                    </div>

                                <div class="col-sm-12">

                                <p>

                                    <button class="viewlist" value="Place Order" type="submit" name="Submit">Online Payment</button>
                                    <button class="viewlist" value="Place Order" type="submit" onclick="window.location='cod.php'" name="COD">Cash On delivery</button>
                                </p>
                                </div>
                            </form>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can Submit form to first PHP script, change target and send it to the second script..

Html:

```
<form id="MyForm" action="Pay.php" target="Frame">
  ...
  <input type="button" onClick="SendToBoth()" value="Send">   
</form>

<iframe name="Frame" style="display: none;"></iframe>
```

Javascript:

```
function SendToBoth(){
  var Form = document.getElementById("MyForm");      
  Form.submit(); // submitting to Pay.php    
  Form.action= "Cod.php";
  Form.submit(); // submitting to Cod.php
  }
```

If you want to show "Cod.php" output, you can remove "target" from Form befire second submit by:

```
function SendToBoth(){
      var Form = document.getElementById("MyForm");      
      Form.submit(); // submitting to Pay.php    
      Form.action= "Cod.php";
      Form.target = "_self";
      Form.submit(); // submitting to Cod.php
      }
```